# Is seven-dimensional cross product rotationally invariant?

Tags: rotations, cross-product, invariance, octonions

For three-dimensional cross product, the following property holds true:
\begin{equation}
(R\mathbf x) \times (R \mathbf y)=R(\mathbf x \times \mathbf y)
\end{equation}
where $R\in SO(3)$.

Is the analogous property (with $R\in SO(7)$) true for [seven-dimensional cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product)?

Comment: Ho do you define the cross product in 7 dimensions?.

Comment: @RogelioMolina Here's the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product

Comment: Well, I haven't verified or thought about it, but the wiki page you linked to says it's not.  Have you tried computing a few examples to try to find a counterexample?

Comment: @Callus Thanks, I didn't notice that short section in the wiki article. I guess this answers the question.

Comment: Look at the rotations section in the wiki entry. It explicitly says that the cross product is not invariant under the group of rotations in seven dimensions, $SO(7)$. Instead, it is is invariant under the exceptional Lie group $G_2$, a subgroup of $SO(7)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: 
$$\mathbf{x}:=(1,0,...,0)^T,\mathbf{y}:=(0,...,0,1)^T\implies \mathbf z:=\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{y}=(0,0,0,0,0,1,0)^T\\
R_{ij}:={1\over\sqrt{2}}(\delta_{i1}\delta_{j1}+\delta_{i2}\delta_{j2}-\delta_{i1}\delta_{j2}+\delta_{i2}\delta_{j1})+\delta_{ij}(1-\delta_{i1})(1-\delta_{i2})\\
R\mathbf{x}={1\over\sqrt{2}}(1,1,0,0,0,0,0)^T\\
R\mathbf{y}={1\over\sqrt{2}}(-1,1,0,0,0,0,0)^T\\
(R\mathbf{x})\times(R\mathbf{y})=(0,0,1,0,0,0,0)^T\\
R\mathbf z=\mathbf z
$$